# Cut out a hole in the shape of a hollow object

Tags: modeling

I've only started using blender 2 days ago. So i'm sorry if this is really stupid. Im not sure what keyterms to search for. but had no luck so far in getting a solution.

1. So, I have a landscape mesh (Another Noise Tool - Landscape), and it is hollow.
2. And I want to set it on a circular plane.
3. but I want to cut out the overlapping part of the circular plane (i highlighted in blue) so I can still see inside the landscape mesh from the bottom.

Essentially, I want the landscape mesh on a circular ground instead of the square it came in. This is the way I thought of going about it. But if there's a more straightforward way, i'd be happy too.

Because the issue with the method I'm trying, it is hard not to have a difference in x-axis between the landscape plane and the circular plane which i circled in green.

I hope you could guide me through it. Thanks!

[image: landscape mesh]
[image: landscape mesh on circular plane]
[image: part i wanna cut out]
[image: x-axis difference]

Answer (score 5):

The most simple way would be if you have the *Loop Tools* addon enabled that comes with Blender.

1. Select the outer edge of the landscape.

[image: select border]

2. Right-click and choose *Loop Tools* > *Circle*.

[image: loop tools]

3. The resulting circle will most likely be too small, so while it's still selected press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it larger and left-click to confirm when you like the size.

[image: small circle]

Finished!

[image: result]

Here a quick summary viewed from the bottom since it seems hard to imagine that the bottom is open as desired:

[image: bottom view summary]

Comment: OP wants the mesh to be open at the bottom, so your answer is missing that part

Comment: @Luciano Follow my instructions **exactly** and look if the bottom is closed...

Comment: oh I'm sorry, of course you're right! That's brilliant. I just read through it too quickly, I thought you were doing boolean with a plane...

Comment: @Luciano No, the boolean workflow is in my other answer  And there the bottom is open as well.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to extrude the outer edge a bit and fill that face to make the thing solid.

[image]

[image]

Then just add a cylinder and use a Boolean modifier with the mode set to Intersect.

If you have the Bool Tool addon enabled (comes with Blender) then you just select the cutter, shift-select object you want to cut and press Ctrl+Numpad /.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all you have your landscape.

[image: landscape]

2. Next you add a cylinder with a not too low resolution. Make it large enough to completely cover the landscape and place it so that the bottom is slightly above the landscape's ground plane.

[image: add cylinder]

3. Now add a *Boolean* modifier to the cylinder. Choose the landscape as the other *Object* and set the mode to *Difference* (you can hide the landscape from view to see the result better). Now you have cut the landscape out of the bottom of the cylinder.

[image: landscape hole]

4. Next apply the modifier by hovering your mouse over it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Tab into *Edit Mode* to select the top face of the cylinder. Then press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Vertices* (important - not *Edges* or *Faces*).

[image: delete top face]

5. It remains the landscape with a circular ground plane. The only problem now is, that the faces are pointing in the wrong direction, because the outside of the landscape was the inside of the cylinder. If you enable *Face Orientation* in the *Overlays* you can see this by the red color instead of blue.

[image: face orientation]

6. To change this, select all faces by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Normals* > *Flip*. Now everything is correct and the top side of the landscape is blue.

[image: result]

The good thing is, the original landscape is still unaltered so you can use it again if you want to redo it slightly different.